# How to save a file to a csv file after groupby().size()

Tags: python, csv, size

Data after `groupby(['Id', 'event']).size()`:

```
1    A       3
     B       1
     C       6
2    A       3
     B       1
```

`data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)` does not yield the format I need in data.csv, which has the column of count.

What I need in data.csv is

```
1    A       3
1    B       1
1    C       6
2    A       3
2    B       1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`df.to_csv(index=False)` omits the index from the output. Use `index=True`, and `header=False` (to omit the column names):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'], 2: [3, 1, 6, 3, 1]})
df = df.set_index([0,1])

print(df.to_csv('data.csv', index=True, header=False, sep='\t'))
```

yields

```
1   A   3
1   B   1
1   C   6
2   A   3
2   B   1
```